# Проблема в реализации пула Тасков

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, tpl

Есть класс пула тасков. Решил переписать метод Start так, что бы вызывать его не таском как было до этого. Тестирую отправку сообщений. Вроде как работает, но есть 2 проблемы:

1. Сообщения посылаются 2 за раз.
2. Блочится основной поток.

Это сама функция старта в созданном классе:

```
    public string Start()
    {
        if (!Active)
        {
            Active = true;
            Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    while (Active)
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(50);
                        if (ListFunc.Count != 0)
                        {
                                await Task.Delay(2000);
                                string a = ListFunc[0].Result;
                                if (ActionEndedEvent != null) ActionEndedEvent(a, ListName[0]);

                            RemoveFromPool(0);
                        }
                    }
                });
            },TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Это пишу в мэин формы:

```
        PoolManager PM = new PoolManager();
        PM.Start();
        PM.Add(test(Привет sjtочень"), "1237");
        PM.Add(test("Привет azrhrhzrчень"), "1234");
        PM.Add(test("Привеzrhrhrhzrh очень"), "1235");
```

Сам таск выглядит так:

```
    async Task<string> test(string message)
    {
        await Task.Delay(10);
        Messages.Send(new SendParams()
        {
            Message = message,
        });
        return "";
    }
```

В чём проблема понять не могу. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Ээээ... А зачем вам пул тасков? Они ж легковесные.

Comment: Задачи **уже** базируются на пуле потоков, нет смысла делать ещё пул задач.

Comment: @ixSci , мне известно что они базируются на пуле потоков, но мне необходимо выделять определенные группы и выполнять их не пересекая их только с задачами из той же группы.

Comment: @VladD , данный таск как пример

Comment: @ixSci , то есть пулы из одного пулл контроллера не могут пересекаться сами с собой, то есть работать поочереди, а с другими тасками они могут как угодно параллельно выполняться.

Comment: Но ведь Вы не контролируете то, на каких потоках задачи будут исполнены, значит Вы не можете гарантировать параллельность или последовательность.

Comment: @ixSci , класс контроллер для этого и сделан. Задача из списка в пределах одного экземпляра контроллера не запускаются пока не завершиться уже запущенная задача, а сами задачи из очереди хранятся в List. То есть задачи в разных экземплярах контроллера они могут параллельно с друг другом выполняться, а задачи внутри одного контроллера запускаются друг за другом после выполнения

Comment: Проблема ещё и в том, что вы не можете перезапустить завершившийся `Task`. В отличие от потоков, которые можно повторно использовать. У вас очень странная задача, расскажите, откуда она взялась и что вам реально нужно.

Comment: @VladD, Ну в целом мне и нету нужды перезапускать таск. Таск отправляется для разовго использования.Контроллер лишь выполняет роль регулировшика, как бы группирует. Тоесть не позволяет таскам внутри так скажем своей группы выполняться параллельно. Но позволяет это делать таскам из разных групп.

Как пример. Есть Апи вконтакте. запрос контакту с одного аккаунта можно отправлять раз в 300 милисекунд и вот этот контроллер позволит сохранять очередь отправки запросов не посылая их одновременно, но с 2х разных аккаунтов можно посылать запросы одновременно и для каждого аккаунта свой контроллер

Comment: VladD, а понять мне нужно как раз те 2 вопроса которые казаны в теме, не могу понять почему они происходят, ведь для контроллера выделен свой поток, и так же почему отправляются 2 сообшения за раз если в таске только одно

Comment: Окей, тогда у вас не пул тасков, а группировка. Раз вам нужно такое, стоит посмотреть в сторону TPL Dataflow? Там ваша задача должна решаться «прямее».

Comment: @VladD, Хорошо, спасибо. А есть ссылочка на какую нибудь вменяемую статью по этой теме?

Comment: @BwehaaFox: Вот [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (смотрите на сайдбар слева) есть набор howto. Но может быть вы сформулируете в вопросе, какое поведение системы вы хотите получить, и может быть такое кто-то напишет ответом.